# why is my ajax request sending a null object to the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to make an ajax request using XMLHttpRequest ... when the processRequest method is called, my MVC action get hit however, the object property values are all null.

**Ajax Class**

```
import {Message} from "./Message";

export class AjaxHelper {

    private url: string;
    private data: Object;
    private callBackFunction: Function;

    constructor(url, data, callback) {
        this.url = url;
        this.data = data;
        this.callBackFunction = callback;
    }

    processRequest(): void {
        //var captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        console.log("from ajax: " + this.data);
        const divOuterNotification = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("divEmailMessage");

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", this.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 300) {
                this.callBackFunction(divOuterNotification, Message.enquirySent);
            } else {
                this.callBackFunction(divOuterNotification, Message.error);
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            this.callBackFunction(divOuterNotification, Message.error);
        }

        xhr.send(this.data);
    }

}
```

**How i call my ajax request**

```
var ajaxObj = new AjaxHelper("/Home/SendEmail", emailEnquiry, this.uiHelper.addNotification);
ajaxObj.processRequest();
```

**MVC Action method**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendEmail(Enquiry emailEnquiry)
{
    return Json("worked");
}
```

The bellow are my objects, the client object and the equivalent of what it should be in C#.

**JS Object**

```
    var emailEnquiry = {
        SenderName: txtNameVal,
        SenderEmail: txtEmailVal,
        SenderTelephone: txtTelephoneVal,
        SenderEnquiry: txtEnquiryVal,
        CaptchaResponse: ""
    };
```

**C# object**

```
public class Enquiry
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string SenderEmail { get; set; }
    public string SenderTelephone { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string SenderEnquiry { get; set; }
    public string CaptchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's inside `emailEnquiry` object ?

Comment: @tchelidze i have updated my question with the emailEnquire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `FromBody` attribute infront of your parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendEmail([FromBody] Enquiry emailEnquiry)
{
    return Json("worked");
}
```

Comment: do you know what `FromBody` attribute is used for ?

Comment: this is for model binding. the json-object should be bound to the requests body. this is needed in asp.net core by json posts

Comment: won't same happen without `FromBody` attribute ?

Comment: only on x-www-form-urlencoded requests. https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this.data));
```